# Parsing SQL - Bash

Tags: sql, bash, unix, awk

I've a certain specific requirement of text parsing of a SQL type file, below are the details.

Huge Query:

```
select
col A,
col B,
.
.
from
(select * from db1.table1 where conditions) t1
left outer join
(select * from db2.table2 where conditions) t2
on table1.col1 = table2.col1
left outer join
(select * from db3.table3 where conditions) t3
on table2.col1 = table3.col3
```

And the query can go on like this. I was trying to parse & modify the query in a specific format like below:

```
select
    col A,
    col B,
    .
    .
    from
    PH1 t1
    left outer join
    PH2 t2
    on table1.col1 = table2.col1
    left outer join
    PH3 t3
    on table2.col1 = table3.col3
```

The Place Holders (PH), I want to put in another separate file; I will call them here in SQL (and this is not the problem).

I'm trying to parse in bash, and really not sure how to replace the inner select queries by place holders. The first half of the query (above first `FROM`) can be segregated by `sed -n '/^SELECT/,/^FROM/p'`.

I'm somehow not able to formulate a logic on how to proceed for the other half requirement.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you use a scripting language such as python, instead of bash?  Might be easier to get working.

Comment: Not very good in Python so first choice was bash :)
Although I'm trying that sideways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk. Is this anything like it:

```
$ awk -v RS="" '{                # read until first empty line or end
    gsub(/\([^)]*\)/,"PH" ++n)   # replace (..) with PHn
    gsub(/\r?\n/,"&    ")        # newlines with newline and space
}1' file                         # output
```

Output:

```
select
    col A,
    col B,
    .
    .
    from
    PH1 t1
    left outer join
    PH1 t2
    on table1.col1 = table2.col1
    left outer join
    PH1 t3
    on table2.col1 = table3.col3
```

Comment: This is perfect. That's why I can't get away from bash :)
Thanks!

Comment: Sir, awk != bash.

Comment: I meant unix; I understand I've had to be specific.